# "Set redefined" Error When Running a Restart Job in Abaqus 6.12-1

Tags: finite-element-method, software

Using Abaqus 6.12-1, I am trying to submit a restart job with an added step. I've followed exactly the instructions in section 19.6.5 of Abaqus 6.12-1 CAE user's manual, but receive this error:

> A node set with the same name "ASSEMBLY_SEM-2D-PART-1_Fixed Nodes" defined in the original analysis has been redefined in the current analysis. Existing sets cannot be modified in a restart analysis.

Looking at the input file for job-2, I see that this is in fact true, Two Nsets used for BCs have been redefined. One is used for a displacement and the other for an encastre. I did not modify these sets in any way. I also checked the .rpy file and it didn't report any changes to sets.

I intend to modify the value for the displacement in the added step. However, to isolate the problem, I have tried the following, none of which have worked.:

1. Not modifying the value for the displacement (propagating it).
2. Deactivating the displacement in the added step.
3. Adding a deactivated step in the original model and activating it upon restart.

Why does this happen?

Also, my end goal is to do this in a Python script. Modifying an input file (manually or programmatically) is not an option.

I can work around the problem as per [agentp's comment](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12743/set-redefined-error-when-running-a-restart-job-in-abaqus-6-12-1#comment22605_12743) and many helpful comments on [this LinkedIn page](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/786907/786907-6211904027945508866). The problem, however, remains unsolved. I'll leave the question open for anyone with the same problem or with a solution to see.

Comment: The input file required for a restart is typically only a few lines. Much easier than monkeying around with CAE. Why rule that out?

Comment: @agentp because then I would have to write all changes to the input file manually. Using CAE/Python, I simply activate a step, and all new Load/BC/Interactions are written automatically.